# How to view NSLog output of XCUITest and my app at the same time?

Tags: xcuitest, xcode10.1

I can perfectly view NSLog lines in my Xcode 10.1 output window of my XCUItest, but I'm not able to see NSLog lines of my actual app/code in the output window.
How can I see NSLog output of my app and my testing at the same time in one window?

And if this it not possible, it would be great if I could switch between my XCUtest and my app output window during testing to see the respective NSlogs. I know I can switch the targets during testing, but if I switch to my real app I don't see any NSLog outputs.

Answer (score 2):

These logs are visible in "Console" app.

If you open it and filter by your app name (PROCESS = app name), you will be able to see them.

[image: screenshot]

It would be interesting to know how to do it in Xcode.